# Ribbon cable for Logitech ClearChat Wireless headset

Tags: cables, ribbon-cable

I'm looking for the name of this cable, which is used in a Logitech ClearChat Wireless headset.
Or a cable with the same endpoints so I can use it as a replacement.

[image: Cable connection point]
[image: Cable top view]
[image: Cable bottom view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cables like that are custom designed to the application for a particular product or product family. The only likely replacement you will likely be able to find new is from the manufacturer.

You may also get lucky and find a like headset that has been thrashed for some other reason and extract the cable from that.

I would start with contacting the manufacturer. Find out the cost involved - if the cable is even available as a spare part - and then weigh that against the cost of simply replacing the whole headset itself.

BTW - What is happened to your existing cable?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.
You can change the headset size by pulling the ears down from the top part, if that explanation makes sense. And while doing that the cable broke.

This headset is a few years old already, so no more guarantee.

But I managed to fix it by soldering the cables back together. Although a replacement cable would be a cleaner fix :)